# Ant build script "try" alternative

Tags: java, ant

I need a block analogous to Java try-catch

if its target failed, I still need to go further and execute the next block.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) [trycatch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) task?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Ant tutorial](https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/ant/ant.html). At the end there is some very comprehensive info on conditional scripts.